# List not getting populated?

Tags: python

I am trying to populate this empty list with a list of users who visit this URL. If the user exists then do not increment 'views' by 1. At the moment 'views' is still getting incremented by 1 every time i refresh the page.

```
    user = request.user
    users = []
    form = BugCommentForm()
    comments = BugComment.objects.filter(bug__pk=bug.pk)
    comments_total = len(comments)
    if user in users:
        bug.save()
    else:
        bug.views += 1
        users.append(user)
        bug.save()
```

Comment: Try to place `users.append(user)` into the if statement (not the else)

Comment: Is this code in a django view function? That means you are reinitializing `users = []` for every request.

Comment: are you creating the empty list `users` every time? (your second line `users=[]`)

Comment: Every time you use users = [] you empty your list. Initiate you list somewhere outside this function so it gets called just in beginning.
Or you can use users.append inside a try and put users = [user] in except.

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to declare  `users` list as Global. you can refer following link 
 details http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm